# Altium: Exclude entire layer from Clearance Rule

Tags: pcb, altium, layout, pcb-layers, clearance

I'm designing a PCB in Altium Designer. I've defined Clearance Rules for certain nets. When I run the DRC (Design Rule Check) I get errors that the Clearance between the Keepout and the Pad doesn't comply (see image below). 
But for me it doesn't matter so I want to **exclude the Keepout-Layer from the Clearance Rules**. How do I do that?

[image: Layout]

##### Error message from the DRC

| Class | Message |
| --- | --- |
| Clearance Constraint Violation | Clearance Constraint: (41.575mil < 78.74mil) Between Pad T310-D(160mil,1480mil) on Multi-Layer And Track (0mil,3937.008mil)(0mil,0mil) on Keep-Out Layer |

#### Clearance Rule

[image: Rule]

---

Altium Designer Version: 22.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the object and go to violations then wave the violation.

You can't exclude an entire layer, only objects in that layer.

If you don't want to do that then you will need to add a custom query.
In the violation details window there will also be a link towards the top of the screen that will take you to the rule that is offending.
Then add in the rule AND ( NOT InComponent('J29') )  or whatever you query needs to be. if its a component that you want to exclude, you can use the query builder to help. You can also check the test queries button before and after to count the number of objects and see if it worked (you should get one less).

Comment: Actually, I could solve it and you can exclude layers. In "Where The Second Object Matches" you can add `not OnLayer('Keep-Out Layer')`

Answer (score 0):

You can  exclude an entire layer by using `OnLayer` to check if the object is on a specific layer.

I could solve the problem by using that. I added following to the rule at `Where The Second Object Matches`:

```
not OnLayer('Keep-Out Layer')
```

[image: Rule]

##### No DRC  error

[image: No_error]